# Chrome ARC - possible to access google account?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

How can I log in to the google account to get available calendars?

I run this code in Android

```
Uri calendars = Uri.parse(String.format("content://%s/calendars", "com.android.calendar"));
Cursor managedCursor = activity.managedQuery(calendars, projection, null, null, null);
// Enumerate and get all calendars
```

I want to do the same in the ARC app, to be able to insert/edit items from the selected calendar. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Calendar sync adapter is not currently supported on ARC.  I filed a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476596) although we might not be able to implement it soon.  Feel free to subscribe the bug for any update.

Comment: Ok, I can try the web API until the bug is fixed, since I guess it will take its time. :)

Comment: It seemed tricky to get the web API to google calendar to work when it's running as a web app. Does anyone have an example how to correctly authencticate yourself against the Calendar API? I've tried GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2  for example, but that doesn't seem to work withing the web app.